# Multithreaded code makes Rhino Mocks cause a Deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, deadlock

We're currently facing some issues during Unit Testing. Our class is multithreading some function calls on Mocked objects using Rhino Mocks. Here's a example reduced to the minimum:

```
public class Bar
{
    private readonly List<IFoo> _fooList;

    public Bar(List<IFoo> fooList)
    {
        _fooList = fooList;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var foo in _fooList)
            allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => foo.DoSomething()));

        Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The Interface IFoo is defined as:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomething();
    event EventHandler myEvent;
}
```

To reproduce the deadlock, our unittest does the following:
1. create some IFoo Mocks
2. Raise myEvent when DoSomething() gets called.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Foo_RaiseBar()
    {
        var fooList = GenerateFooList(50);

        var target = new Bar(fooList);
        target.Start();
    }

    private List<IFoo> GenerateFooList(int max)
    {
        var mocks = new MockRepository();
        var fooList = new List<IFoo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            fooList.Add(GenerateFoo(mocks));

        mocks.ReplayAll();
        return fooList;
    }

    private IFoo GenerateFoo(MockRepository mocks)
    {
        var foo = mocks.StrictMock<IFoo>();

        foo.myEvent += null;
        var eventRaiser = LastCall.On(foo).IgnoreArguments().GetEventRaiser();

        foo.DoSomething();
        LastCall.On(foo).WhenCalled(i => eventRaiser.Raise(foo, EventArgs.Empty));

        return foo;
    }
```

The more Foo's are generated, the more often the deadlock occurs. If the test won't block, run it several times, and it will.
Stopping the debugging testrun shows, that all Tasks are still in TaskStatus.Running and the current worker thread is breaking at

> [In a sleep, wait, or join]
>     Rhino.Mocks.DLL!Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInvocation
>   invocation) + 0x3d bytes

The weird thing which confuses us most is the fact, that the signature of the Intercept(...) Method is defined as Synchronized - but several Threads are located here. I've read several postings about Rhino Mocks and Multithreaded, but havn't found warnings (expected setting up the records) or limitations.

```
 [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
```

Are we doing something completely wrong on setting up our Mockobjects or using them in a multithreaded environment? Any help or hint is welcome!

Comment: I found this [http://blog.smithfamily.dk/post/2011/03/26/Thread-safe-version-of-Rhino-Mocks.aspx](http://blog.smithfamily.dk/post/2011/03/26/Thread-safe-version-of-Rhino-Mocks.aspx) on my google travels. Sadly, the version hosted there seems to have a bug in it, so I cant see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a race condition in your code and not a bug in RhinoMocks. The problem occurs when you are setting up the allTasks task list in the `Start()` method:

```
public void Start() 
{ 
    var allTasks = new List<Task>(); 
    foreach (var foo in _fooList) 
        // the next line has a bug
        allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => foo.DoSomething())); 

    Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray()); 
}
```

You need to pass the foo instance explicitly into the task. The task will execute on a different thread and it's very likely that the foreach loop will replace the value of foo before the task has started.

This means that each `foo.DoSomething()` is being invoked sometimes never and sometimes more than once. For this reason, some of the tasks will block indefinitely because RhinoMocks can't handle overlapped raising of events on the same instance from different threads and it gets into a deadlock.

Replace this line in your `Start` method:

```
allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => foo.DoSomething()));
```

With this:

```
allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(f => ((IFoo)f).DoSomething(), foo));
```

This is a classic bug that is subtle and very easy to overlook. It is sometimes referred to as "accessing a modified closure".

PS:

Following the comments on this post, I rewrote this test using Moq. In this case it doesn't block - but beware that expectations created on a given instance might not be satisfied unless the original bug is fixed as described. GenerateFoo() using Moq looks like this:

```
private List<IFoo> GenerateFooList(int max)
{
    var fooList = new List<IFoo>();

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        fooList.Add(GenerateFoo());

    return fooList;
}

private IFoo GenerateFoo()
{
    var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
    foo.Setup(f => f.DoSomething()).Raises(f => f.myEvent += null, EventArgs.Empty);
    return foo.Object;
}
```

It's more elegant than RhinoMocks - and clearly more tolerant of multiple threads raising events on the same instance simultaneously. Although I don't imagine this is a common requirement - personally I don't often find scenarios where you can assume the subscribers to an event are thread-safe.

Comment: +1 - yes that's a foreach closure problem (a temp variable would do too) - and you might have only one foo called 50 times - but does that 'yield' the deadlock? I'm not that familiar w/ Rhino (though mock is a mock:) but doesn't look like anything there blocks, explicitly at least (mock code). IMO you'd get 50 events fired on just one foo, but still looks set to end.

Comment: Deadlock is on RhinoInterceptor.Intercept method which is marked with the SynchronizedAttribute, equivalent to a lock(this). Bad news once you've got multiple threads executing on the same instance. I haven't followed the whole chain of calls in the debugger step by step (I don't fancy reverse engineering RhinoMocks and Castle - that code is hairy!), but I spotted that calls to Intercept appear multiple times within a stack - so looks like a deadlock caused by two threads that have passed through Intercept once on different objects and are holding locks now trying to acquire each others'.

Comment: that makes more sense :), now it's clear - but it's still IMO the fault of the Rhino's design - as there is nothing in there that justifies the locks (though I can understand how one could get there easily) -  
i.e. if you handcraft the Mock (manual class) it should work w/o problems - if I'm not mistaken  
i.e. the bug with the closure is just bringing up the problems that lie under the hood  
...while that could solve the locking (so it is an answer to the specific Q - but then again someone wanted this cleared related to Rhino seems) - you'd get trapped soon again. I too didn't debug so...

Comment: Thanks - updated my answer with additional information about this. I added the Moq equivalent - which works fine. I prefer the way Moq handles events, but don't think you can be too hard on RhinoMocks here as a genuine need for this the scenario would be pretty unusual.

Comment: ok, sadly the above solution wont work for me, as it requires reworking a fair bit of functionality. Our live target 'foo' is thread safe, but rhino is not. Thanks for the info though, you've  really done your work, and explained the problem, deserved points.

Answer (score 2):

Maggie, Not obvious to me from the sample but something that might help you if you have Visual studio Ultimate... Once you deadlock, Break all to get into the debugger then go to the Debug menu and select:

Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks

Visual studio builds a nice graph showing the states of all the running threads. From there you usually get some kind of hint as to which locks are in contention.